# Inductor with ac and dc

Tags: ac, electromagnetism, inductance

When a dc voltage source is connected with a pure inductor

And the switch is closed

We get a change in voltage across inductor and along with it a also an attempt to change the current across the inductor.

We get equal and opposite voltage across inductor against the source voltage(Faraday and Lenz law) at t = 0.

But then as time passes we get increase /change in current across the inductor at a constant rate. di/dt = V/L.

Now when we connect ac with a pure inductor.

We have always changing voltage across the inductor and consequently always changing current across the inductor.

So can i assume that for every infinitesimal change in voltage and current across the inductor in case of ac there will always be equal and opposite voltage across the inductor which will block the current initially for a while for that infinitesimal change and then will allow the current to change at a constant rate for that infitesimal change of voltage and current?

Comment: Applied voltage \$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}\$ - are you still disputing that this is true?

Comment: I am sure this is true. Actually Farcher told me that for every change in voltage electric fields and magnetic field change in the circuit which cause equal and opposite voltage in inductor. That equal and opposite voltage stops current to flow for a while but then allows the current to change at some constant rate. Now i want to confirm that whether it happens in both ac and dc or just in dc.